# WordPress Theme - Can't Find Style Source File

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming

For this WordPress site, I need to substitute the border line for the links with an image. [image]

Currently, it's set for a yellow border line to appear when you hover over the links like this:[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to change the lines to a paw print that I created in illustrator (this is a website about dogs).

[image]

As you can see in the first screenshot, this is how the a links are styled:

```
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a {
color: #ffde15;
}

.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a {
border-top: 3px solid transparent;
height: 83px:
line-height: 83px;
font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 18px:
}
```

And the styling continues...

[image]

[image]

[image]

As I look through the stylesheet (style.css) for the WordPress theme (Avada) I do a command + f for this string and it's style:

```
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a {
border-top: 3px solid transparent;
height: 83px:
line-height: 83px;
font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 18px:
}
```

I will need to change "border-top" to this:

```
background-image: url (images/"pawprint.png");
```

But that exact string is nowhere to be found in style.css. I can find

```
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a
```

five times but I can't find one that has the following style inside of it:

```
{
border-top: 3px solid transparent;
height: 83px:
line-height: 83px;
font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 18px:
}
```

I noticed that the first two styles in the console show "(index):90" as the source while the remaining styles show "style.css" as the source. What is "(index):90" and where can I find it so that I can make the appropriate changes (by using a child theme)?

Comment: Can't you just edit the Quick CSS area, and use the same class to add the background file to? (index):90 means the theme is pulling the CSS from somewhere and adding it into the <head> of the document, inside of an internal <style> tag.

Comment: I'm sorry what's the Quick CSS area? You mean in the console on the right of developer tools? Oh so it's an inline style like <p style=".....">?

Comment: `:90` is the line number the selector appears on.

Comment: @HappyHands31 no, it appears in the `<head>` of a site, so it should be found inside a `<style type="text/css">...</style>` tag. You cannot use CSS selectors in inline styles, aka `style="..."`.

Comment: @hungerstar Oh so then I need to find index.php and look for line 90 to edit the style?

Comment: Not necessarily, those styles are likely being injected into the `<head>`. You might have to look into `functions.php` or elsewhere. I believe @Garconis meant that you could add CSS to the `<head>` via the admin of the site, `Admin => Appearance => Editor`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Avada theme options, but yes, most themes have a custom CSS area, for these purposes... So that you don't have to edit any theme files directly.

Comment: I've looked around on WordPress and so far haven't been able to find a way to edit the style through the front-end....so even though it says index, it could be header.php, functions.php.....do we realy have a way of knowing?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you can't find some part of code, you can open theme folder as "project" in the preferred text editor (Sublime, Atom etc.) and search for required string.

But anyway, you can always use Theme Quick CSS modifier inside theme options.